# R - 'unlist' methods for list of custom classes

Tags: r

I have some custom classes, for example:

```
setClass("foo", slots = c(mat = "matrix"))
```

I want to handle how a list of `foo` objects are 'unlisted'.

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4)
foo <- new("foo", mat = mat)
unlist(list(foo))
```

I thought perhaps creating methods for `c` (which I thought was used but perhaps incorrectly) and `unlist` would solve the problem.

S3 version

```
#' @export
unlist <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("unlist", x)

#' @export
unlist.default <- base::unlist
#' @method unlist foo
#' @export
unlist.foo <- function(x, ...){
  print("called foo unlist")
}
```

S4 version

```
#' @export
setMethod("unlist",
          signature = "foo",
          function(x, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE){
            print("call foo unlist")
          })
```

`c` function

```
#' @export
setMethod("c", 
          signature = "foo",
          function(x, ..., recursive = FALSE){
            print("called foo c")
})
```

But I only see the confirmation message when I use `c` directly:

```
c(foo)
[1] "called foo c"
```

The `unlist` just returns the same object with no print message

```
unlist(list(foo))
[[1]]
An object of class "foo"
Slot "mat":
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,]  0.6711541 -0.2783441 -0.4707375 -0.23060105
[2,]  0.7408401  0.4076826  2.2757187 -0.48547413
[3,]  1.8640581  0.3610619 -0.4632473 -0.06498348
[4,] -0.5595930  0.6679157 -0.8142456  0.27499963
```

If I call `unlist(foo)` then I get the print message but I need to apply it on a list of the `foo` objects.  Any thoughts on how I can have unlist deal with custom classes within a list?

Ultimately I want the following to return `TRUE`:

```
all.equal(unlist(list(foo)), unlist(list(mat)))
```

Comment: `unlist` doesn't look like an S3 method. If you want to use your function, you need to directly call `unlist.foo`

Comment: @Chrisss Although I used `roxygen2` to export it as an S3 I have now explicitly instantiated `unlist` as S3.  It still results in the same problem.

Comment: `unlist.foo` would be a method for S3, which would apply to an object such as `foo <- structure(matrix(rnorm(16), 4), class = "foo")` but your class looks like S4 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @baptiste I just now tried to use an S4 method.  Still the same result.

Comment: @cdeterman Hold on, maybe I misread the question. What exactly is the problem? Using the S4 method...`c(foo)` and `unlist(foo)` give you the output you specified in your functions. `unlist(list(foo))` obvious uses `base::unlist` because the function is being applied on an object of class `list`. Ie. `class(list(foo))`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Chrisss how can I have the unlist call behave differently for specific classes in the list?

Comment: @Chrisss Does that make sense?  My actual class doesn't behave as nicely as the `foo` class here.  I need to handle different types of classes within a `list` with `unlist`.

Comment: @cdeterman I don't quite understand. Do you want `unlist` to act on `list(foo)` as if it's acting on `foo`? Or do you want to unlist to do different things to elements of a list depending on the element's class? Then, just apply `unlist` element by element. `lt <- list(foo, mat); lapply(lt, unlist)`. Sorry, I can't be of more help, I don't quite see your problem clearly.

Comment: @Chrisss I want `unlist(list(foo))` to provide the same output as `unlist(list(mat))`.  I thought `unlist` would be recursive for each element type but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is not possible. `unlist` determines the type of its output based on types of individual elements of the list it gets. If all elements are atomic, like in case the only element is `foo` (a matrix), it does something to its argument -- coerces arguments to common atomic vector (there is only one) and forgets most of its attributes (e.g. dimensions). However, it does not treat S4 objects (like `foo`), that happen to be based on atomic vectors, as atomic vectors: these S4 objects will be hence left intact in the result, and the result will be of type list. So calling `unlist` on `list(foo)` returns `list(foo)`. The behavior is implemented in C (`do_unlist` in `bind.c`) and seems to me to be in line with the documentation.

To mimick the desired behavior in a subset of possible usages of `unlist`, one could probably implement a new class for a list of `foo` objects, define `list` for `foo`, and then define a new `unlist` for this list-of-foo class to behave similarly to how the default C implementation of unlist behaves on a list of atomic vectors (I haven't tried).